# Why Genitive in "was des Kummers nicht wert ist"

Tags: genitive

The sentence goes like

> "Während du gelehrte Worte sprichst, betrauerst du, was des Kummers nicht wert ist."

I gathered, some prepositions take the genitive case and "Während" is one of them but here "Während"  is a conjunction.

Comment: Would you please add the source of that sentence?

Comment: @Arsak, https://www.vedabase.com/de/bg/2/11

Answer (score 6):

The genitive in your example is **not** caused by a preposition or conjunction.

It is actually caused by the adjective *wert* - There are a number of ***adjectives*** that rule the genitive like

> bar, begierig, bewusst, eingedenk, fähig, frei, froh, fündig, gedenk, gewahr, gewärtig, gewiss, gewohnt, habhaft, kundig, ledig, mächtig, müde, satt, schuldig, sicher, teilhaft, teilhaftig, überdrüssig, unbenommen, unbeschadet, ungeachtet, ungedenk, unkund, unkundig, unteilhaft, unweit, unwert, unwürdig, verdächtig, verlustig, voll, voller, weitab, wert, würdig

Some example sentences:

> Er handelte bar jedes Verstandes
>
> Er war sich der Tatsache bewusst
>
> Sie war des Wartens überdrüssig
>
> Das Kind war voll der Freude
>
> Er ist unserer Verehrung würdig
>
> Die Polizei konnte des Täters habhaft werden
>
> Er ist deiner Anteilnahme nicht wert

Most of these genitive constructs driven from adjectives are on the retreat in modern German and more and more only used in standing expressions - Or texts that clearly lean towards pathos, like your example.

A modern way of expressing the same thing would be, for example, using an infinitive construct like

> Während du gelehrte Worte sprichst, betrauerst du, was es nicht wert ist, darüber bekümmert zu sein.

Comment: thank you, so that means - "des müde Junge" is correct but archaic?

Comment: Not quite - that is too simple. You could say "der Junge war ihrer ständigen Ausreden müde" - meaning "the boy was tired of her permanent excuses".

Answer (score 2):

The genitive is used not because of während but because of wert sein:

> jemandes, einer Sache/eine Sache wert sein (jemandes, einer Sache würdig sein; jemanden, etwas verdienen; eine bestimmte Mühe lohnen: sie ist dieses Mannes nicht wert;

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wert

Answer (score -1):

In another reading, rather transparently, *wert* can be interpreted as the noun, thus little change around the semantics

> das ist nicht [der] Wert des Kummers

lack of the article "[der]" is natural in certain instances, eg. *das ist nicht _ Sinn der Sache*. *500 Steine ist des Wagens wert/Wert* also works either way, but is uncommon either way, too.

That does not quite fit with several of @tofro's examples. Still these may be seen as having deverbals that act like nouns in the syntactic place of an adjective - i.e. participles - especially in the first one that has a parallel in En. *baring all good reason*, etc; Further: *voll der Freude* also appears as *erfüllt von Freude*, *voller Freude* or *voll Freude*, at least, whereas En. *full of joy* would relate rather to the opaque idiom *vollauf begeistert* (cp. Nl. *op*); *bewusst sein* readily comes with the noun *Bewusstsein*, and *im Bewusstsein dessen* still requires genitive, but *dessen Bewusstsein* would be posessive, not transitive, nevertheless the transitive *Ihm wurde bewusst* can be read as passive construction of * *bewissen*.

It is hard to tell where this idiom around *wert sein* started, but today it is predominantly *Der Wagen ist den Preis nicht wert*, or *Den Aufwand ist der Lohn nicht wert*, which respectively switch the position of the comparands. Whereas *der Wert des Geldes* describesvan inherent quality without comparison. This modern reading would give the unintended meaning, that the act of "bedauern" does not satisfy the expense of the "Kummer", or any other thinkable constalation.